# Mysql query return false even the condition is true

Tags: php, mysql

```
$checkexist = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mentoraktivitisum WHERE noFP = '$noFP' AND sesi = '$sesi') or die(mysql_error()");
```

When i var_dump $checkexist, it display boolean(false), even the condition in query true.

I check in phpmyadmin, the query is correct. I got 1 if row exist and 0 if not exist.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should read about using prepared statements in PHP.

Comment: I think your query and your code are mixed up. Can you post the query that you run in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: `$checkexist` isn't the result of the query. It's just whether the query was successful or got an error.

Comment: `or die(mysql_error()` shouldn't be in the query string.

Comment: You're also mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions. That won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take `or die` out of the query. Then you need to fetch the row of the results.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mentoraktivitisum WHERE noFP = ? AND sesi = ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $noFP, $sesi);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$checkexists = $row[0];
```